# Increase speed of reading gz file in C

Tags: c, performance, file-io, gzip

I have written a small `C` program. It does read some gzipped files, does some filtering and then again outputs to gzipped files.

I run gcc with `-O3 -Ofast`. Otherwise pretty standard.

If I do `strace -c` on my executable I get:

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 46.01    0.077081           0    400582           read
 42.73    0.071579        4771        15           munmap
  9.34    0.015647           0    110415           brk
  1.01    0.001688          32        52           openat
  0.45    0.000746           3       228           mmap
  0.20    0.000327           4        70           mprotect
  0.15    0.000254           0      1128           write
  0.06    0.000100           2        50           fstat
  0.05    0.000087           1        52           close
  0.00    0.000006           6         1           getrandom
  0.00    0.000005           2         2           rt_sigaction
  0.00    0.000004           2         2         1 arch_prctl
  0.00    0.000003           3         1         1 stat
  0.00    0.000003           1         2           lseek
  0.00    0.000002           2         1           rt_sigprocmask
  0.00    0.000002           2         1           prlimit64
  0.00    0.000000           0         8           pread64
  0.00    0.000000           0         1         1 access
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           execve
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           fdatasync
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_tid_address
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_robust_list
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.167534                512616         3 total
```

So my program is quite busy with reading the file. Now, I am not sure if I can get it faster. The relevant code is the following:

```
  while (gzgets(file_pointer, line, LL) != Z_NULL) {
       linkage = strtok(line,"\t");
       linkage = strtok(NULL,"\t");
       linkage[strcspn(linkage, "\n")] = 0;

       add_linkage_entry(id_cnt, linkage);

       id_cnt++;
    }
```

Do you see see room for improvement here? Is it possible to intervene manually with `gzread` or is `gzgets` doint a good job here to not read char by char?

Any other advice? (Are the errors in the `strace` worrisome?)

EDIT:
`add_linkage_entry` does add an entry to a `uthash` hash table (https://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/)

Comment: The number of `read` system call is huge and very likely the bottleneck in your code. It may be because there are a lot of files to archive (if so using a RAM FS can help but note that moving the file will be roughly as expensive). Alternatively, it can be cause the operation is not buffered or the buffer is too small. It is very hard to tell without a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: (1) Is your `LL` sufficiently large for the longest line in the input file? (2) Does your input file have 400,582 lines?

Comment: @VladFeinstein (1) Yes, LL is 128 chars while my longest line is 79 chars. (2) the file has many more lines (about 2-3 orders of magnitude more lines) -- I guess this an indication that "gzgets" is reading buffered from the gzipped files -- which would be good, right?

Comment: why are you overwriting linkage ?

Comment: @MitchWheat The first assignment would actually not be necessary (linkage = strtok(line,"\t");). But the speed gain would probably be minor if I remove this.

Comment: regardless of the speed gain, code should be logically correct.

Comment: @MitchWheat Sure, you are right!

Comment: `strace` is only giving you the system calls, which is very likely not where your program is spending most of its time or even a significant amount of its time. Look up how to profile your code on your system and compiler. What does `add_linkage_entry()` do?

Comment: First thing first. If you run `time ./your-program`, what kind of output do you get? What dominates,  `user` or `sys`? Do `user` and `sys` add up (approximately) to `real`, or there is a large gap? Knowing these things allows you to answer quickly whether your program is CPU bound or IO bound.

Comment: @MarkAdler See my edit above regarding add_linkage_entry()

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that `gzgets` (and the related `read` system calls) are the bottleneck here.

The number of `read` calls is small for data that compresses well, and it will increase for data that has more entropy (`zlib` has to request uncompressed data from disk more frequently then). E.g., for text data generated from `urandom` (via

```
base64 /dev/urandom | tr -- '+HXA' '\t' | head -n 10000000 | gzip
```

) I get about 70000 `read` calls for 10M lines, equalling about 140 lines/call. This nicely matches your experience of 100..1000 lines per call.

What is more, the CPU time for reading those lines is still negligible (about 2.5M lines/s, including the `strtok` calls). Highly compressed data requires about 40 times fewer `read` calls and can be read about 4 times as fast -- but this factor of 4 can also be seen with raw decompression via `gzip -d` on the command lines.

**It thus appears that your function `add_linkage_entry` is the bottleneck here**. In particular the large number of `brk` calls looks unusal.

The errors in strace output look harmless.